# Betta sick; not sure what's wrong

Tags: fish, betta

My betta all of a sudden took a turn for the worse. I automatically thought it was fin rot as both fins look as though they've been nibbled on. I've treated the tank for fin rot and fungus, but he's still under the weather. Please refer to pics.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please describe his overall condition. Does he lay like that the whole time or does he move? For how long has he been like that? Did he eat well before becomming like this? What are the latest readings of the water quality (and when did you last test the water)?

Comment: So he lays alot like this most the day . Sometimes just floating around to move and then back to the bottom again. Water was tested straight away no signs of anything .. ammonia test reading safe... recently done a water change with the correct chemicals to kill chlorine . He was fine 1 day and the next I saw him laying on the floor was eating fine before also . Hes also kept with a catfish . But that seems totally fine .

Comment: Along with the  ammonia readings, how are the nitrite and nitrate readings? As well as pH of the water. Additionally, is the tank filtered and heated? How many gallons is the tank? He looks a little bloated, so I might fast him for while, it could be a swim bladder condition.

Comment: Does the fish "sink" when not swimming ?

Comment: He does sink when swimming .. he does seem to swim ok when he picks up the energy to do so .. he has slightly cloudy eyes . The levels on the tank are how they should be exactly the same as my other fish tank .. the ammonia is constantly being checked also the PH, which are fine .. he has a heated well filter tank and hes in a 15L  not sure what that is in Gallons

Comment: Sorry doesn't sink

Comment: Any major temperature changes? We had a mini-heatwave here (I’m not in a warm region but the temps rose about 12C nearly overnight) and it made one of my goldfish look ill and wiped out for a day or so. It’s ok now. Might be ok if the tank temp is controlled (mine isn’t heated). Also, is he old?